# Angular2Token consume data from additionally user interface

Tags: angular

I have a working user registration with additional attributes like firstname and lastname in a interface. I set this up as Angular interface and call the userdata with the GET request from the Angular2Token example, which bring me back the all data.

`export interface User {last_name: string, first_name: string}`

**auth.service.ts**

```
user: User[];

getProfileData() {
return this._tokenService.get(this.userDataUrl + '.json')
  .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
      this.user = data.user;
      console.log(data);
      return data
    },
    error => {console.log(error)
    }
  );
}
```

My idea is now to load the JSON data into a profile page with a form that the user can edit his data. But with my exisitng method I can't access the data from the interface.

**profile.component.ts**

```
getUserData() {
  this.authService.getProfileData();
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.getUserData();
}
```

Would be great if someone can show me where I missed something to get this data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to cache the user in the provider you should use .do().

Then do not subscribe your service call in the service, do that in the component to take advantage of the lazy loading.

```
getProfileData() {
  return this._tokenService.get(this.userDataUrl + '.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .do(data => {
      this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
      this.user = data.user;
      console.log(data);
      return data
    });
}




getUserData() {
  this.authService.getProfileData().subscribe(.....).catch(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.